# How to handle unused warnings caused by empty template parameter pack expansions?

Tags: c++11, gcc, clang, variadic-templates, compiler-warnings

An issue I keep facing is one where the compiler complains about an unused variable, even though the variable is used, but it's only used inside a parameter pack expansion that happens to be empty for a specific instantiation.
For example:

```
template <std::size_t... I>
auto func1(std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
  auto var = get_tuple();
  return func2(std::get<I>(var)...);
}

auto a = func1(std::make_index_sequence<0>());
```

See [live example](https://godbolt.org/g/Ahywrv) (try changing the tuple at line 4, by adding an int inside <> to see the warning go away).
I know I could add a `(void)var;` line to make the warning go away, but it feels dirty to me, especially when the function is actually just a single line.
I also don't want to disable this warning globally, because it does provide insight sometimes.

A similar manifestation of this issue is when the variable is used in a lambda capture. In this case, gcc spits no warning, while clang complains (I think gcc never implemented a warning about unused lambda captures):

```
template <std::size_t... I>
auto func1(std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
  auto var = get_tuple();
  auto my_lambda = [var](){
    return func2(std::get<I>(var)...);
  };
  return my_lambda();
}

auto a = func1(std::make_index_sequence<0>());
```

[clang example](https://godbolt.org/g/CrwNhM)

Comment: Use clang and file a bug report to gcc :P

Comment: You can still `pragma push/pop` around the function to disable warning. but `static_cast<void>(var);` seems better workaround.

Comment: How about `return func2(std::get<I>(get_tuple())...);`?

Comment: @Jarod42 It might not be obvious this is to silence a warning instead of a botched up job of forcing a read from `var` or some other weirdness

Comment: @nwp Isn't that going to execute `get_tuple` multiple times, which may or may not always return the same thing? Also maybe be a performance problem if it does a lot of stuff.

Comment: @Rakete1111 clang maybe handles the regular unused variable better, but complains when this variable is in a lambda capture.

Comment: @nwp this is just a minimal example to show the warning, not something I intend to use in production (and also what Rakete1111 replied as well).

Answer (score 7):

If you can use C++17, the `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute is the clearest solution IMO:

```
[[maybe_unused]]
auto tuple = get_tuple();
```

Comment: How would you use it when the variable is in a lambda capture: https://godbolt.org/g/CrwNhM

Comment: @dcmm88 File a bug, because you are using `var`. Here's a workaround: https://godbolt.org/g/xLzKnB

Answer (score 5):

`var` is indeed not use with empty pack.
Is it intended ? compiler can only guess.

Whereas clang consider than empty pack is a usage, gcc chooses the contrary.

You can silent the warning in different ways as:

- attribute `[[maybe_unused]]` (C++17)
- casting to `void` (`static_cast<void>(arg)`)
- or similar (`template <typename T> void unused_var(T&&){}` and then `unused_var(var)`).
- creating overloads:

  ```
  auto func1(std::index_sequence<>)
  {
    return func2();
  }

  template <std::size_t... I>
  auto func1(std::index_sequence<I...>)
  {
    auto var = get_tuple();
    return func2(std::get<I>(var)...);
  }
  ```

  or in C++17

  ```
  template <std::size_t... I>
  auto func1(std::index_sequence<I...>)
  {
      if constexpr (sizeof ...(I) == 0) {
          return func2();
      } else {
          auto var = get_tuple();
          return func2(std::get<I>(var)...);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: A c-style cast to void is one of the few cases where C-style casts can provably not do bad behavior.  In addition, `unused_var` could accidentally force ODR-existence of a variable if used without care.

Comment: `[[maybe_unused]]` is not supported by GCC prior to 7

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a compiler bug in GCC. The easiest workaround is to mark `var` with `[[gnu::unused]]`:

```
template <std::size_t... I>
auto func1(std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
  auto var [[gnu::unused]] = get_tuple();
  return func2(std::get<I>(var)...);
}
```

If you are force to use compilers that don't recognize `[[gnu::unused]]`, you can fake use the variable with a `static_cast<void>`:

```
template <std::size_t... I>
auto func1(std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
  auto var = get_tuple();
  static_cast<void>(var);
  return func2(std::get<I>(var)...);
}
```

Comment: Will this wreck portability?

Comment: If an attribute is not recognized, the compiler ignores it. And both GCC and LLVM support `[[gnu::unused]]`.

Comment: Wouldn't unrecognized attributes also spit out warnings? [Like this](https://godbolt.org/g/oz9cwR)

Comment: Depends on your compiler settings :-)

Comment: For the second solution (the only one I know how to make it work for a lambda capture: https://godbolt.org/g/CrwNhM), isn't it preventing the optimizer from completely eliminating var from the compiler output?

Comment: If you turn on optimization, it goes away.

Answer (score 2):

`(void)var;` suppressed unused warnings in every compiler I have used:

```
template <std::size_t... I>
auto func1(std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
  auto var = get_tuple();
  (void)var;
  return func2(std::get<I>(var)...);
}
auto a = func1(std::make_index_sequence<0>());
```

`(void)variable;` has zero run time effects.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe there are other problems but... according the code you linked in compiler explorer, your `var` is a `std::tuple<>`; that is a `std::tuple` with zero components.

If I'm not wrong, `std::get<Num>(std::tuple<Ts..>)` is defined only when `Num` is in `[0,sizeof...(Ts))`; in this case in `[0, 0)`, that is an empty interval.

I suppose that your code (when `var` is defined as `std::tuple<>`) is ill formed. So I suppose that the warning is correct (because there isn't cases when `var` is used) but doesn't warn about the real problem.

It's different when `var` is defined as `std::tuple<int>`: `var` is correctly used when all `I` are equal to zero, so `var` is (potentially) used and, as you observed, the warning disappears.

Comment: But if `var` is empty, the code expands to nothing, no?

Comment: @Rakete1111 - I suppose you're right but (if I'm not wrong) `var` is never unused; when `sizeof...(I)` is zero and when is grater. So the warning message. When the OP transform `var` in a `std::tuple<int>`, the warning disappear because (as ever: if I'm not wrong) there are cases when `var` is correctly used: when (and only when) all `I` are zero.

Comment: Agreed, the code uses `var`, so the warning is wrong. Not sure I understand your last point.

Comment: @Rakete1111 - my last point is that if `var` is a `std::tuple<>` (warning case), `var` is **never** used (also when `sizeof...(I)` is greater than zero); when `var` is a `std::tuple<int>` (no warning case), `var` is (correctly!) used when all `I` are equal to zero. So (if I'm not wrong, as usual) the compiler is right (in both cases) but, in the first case, the real problem is another (a call to `std::get<I>(var)` when `var` is a `std::tuple<>` is wrong in any case).

Comment: @max66 Yes, the reason it complains about unused variables is that the parameter pack expansion is empty. So `var` isn't really used after expansion. But my whole point is that the warning is useless for me. Note that clang doesn't complain about the exact same code (though it complains in another case). Also, nothing in my code is UB. There is nothing wrong with `std::get<I>(var)` when `var` is a `std::tuple<>`, because it's part of parameter pack expansion expression that evaluates to nothing. So there is never a call such as `std::get<??>(var)` being made.

Comment: @dcmm88 - I see... well, I'm not a standard layer but... according it, a call to `std::get<I>(var)` (whan `var` is a `std::tuple<>`) is "ill formed"; but you're righr: when `sizeof...(I) == 0`, the ill formed call isn't expanded; sorry but I don't if this is enough to make you're code not "ill formed" (maybe I'll write another question, about it). Anyway, I think the compuler is correct emitting a warning and, in cases like this one, I suppose that a `(void)var` is an acceptable solution.

Comment: @dcmm88 - en passant, I think you should make more clear, in your question, that `var` is a `std::tuple<>` (when you get the warning).

Comment: @max66 but it doesn't have to be. The example would still be valid even if `get_tuple` returns an `std::tuple<int>`.

Comment: @dcmm88 - the case `std::tuple<int>` is different (from the point of view of the compiler, when compile `func1()`) because there are possible calls to `func1()` (by example: `func1(std::make_index_sequence<1>());`) that cause the use of `var`; with `std::tuple<>`, with every call to `func1()` `var` is unused. (As usual: if I'm not wrong).

Comment: @max66 I was just replying to your suggestion to make the question clearer by explaining that `get_tuple` returns an `std::tuple<>`. What I said was that even if `get_tuple`'s return type was `std::tuple<int>` (while my example stays exactly the same with the call to `make_index_sequence<0>`, the behavior I was referring to would still exist (the compiler would still complain about an unused variable). So, in summary, the kind of tuple `get_tuple` returns is irrelevant to my question/example.

Comment: @dcmm88 - I hope that something more expert than me can see your improved question. What I trying to say is that the compiler, for a template function, doesn't evaluate only the call with `make_index_sequence<0>` but consider if there is a call when `var` is used; in the case `std::tuple<>`, there isn't; with `std::tuple<int>`, a using-`var` call is possible (`make_index_sequence<1>`).