# zero length variadic expansion of ill-formed call

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, well-formed

Question for standard gurus.

Trying to respond to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46473038/how-to-handle-unused-warnings-caused-by-empty-template-parameter-pack-expansions), I came to doubt about the well-formedness of a code.

As far I know, the following code is  ill-formed

```
int main ()
 {
   std::tuple<>  a;

   std::get<0>(a);
 }
```

because a call to `std::get<I>(t)`, when `t` is a `std::tuple<Ts...>`, is ill-formed when `I` is outside the range `[0, sizeof...(Ts)[`.

In this case `sizeof...(Ts)` is zero, so the range `[0, 0[` is empty, so `std::get<I>(a)` is ill-formed for every index `I`.

But when `std::get<I>(a)` is expanded through an empty variadic pack?

I mean: the following code

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename ... Args>
void bar (Args const & ...)
 { }

template <std::size_t ... I>
void foo ()
 {
   std::tuple<> a;

   bar( std::get<I>(a) ... );
 }

int main ()
 {
   foo<>();
 }
```

that uses a ill-formed (?) call (`std::get<I>(a)`) but zero-time variadic expanded (`sizeof...(I)` is zero), is well-formed or ill-formed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[[temp.res]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.res#8):

> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> - [...]
> - every valid specialization of a variadic template requires an empty template parameter pack, or
> - [...]

Comment: Note that it is ill formed as OP tried to simplify the problem :-/ (as original is nearer that `get<Is>(tuple_of_size<Is>{})...`).

Comment: As an aside, this means when implementing apply it is tricky to avoid this trap.

Comment: @Jarod42 - sorry: with "as original" do you mean from the question I've linked?

Comment: @max66: yes indeed.

Comment: @Jarod42 - I see. But, if I'm not wrong, in that question (see the code linked in "compiler explorer") `var` is a `std::tuple<>` (and the warning disappear when is a `std::tuple<int>`).

Comment: @T.C. - thanks for your answer that show me a rule I didn't know and solve the doubt I've expressed in this question. But I'm not sure how it should be interpreted this rule for templates with two or more parameter packs. But I suppose is better if I write another question. Thanks again. (p.s.: I hate "no diagnostic required")

Comment: @T.C. - added a [new related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46502745/template-well-formedness-and-zero-pack-length-rule); hoping you can give a look.

Comment: does this really apply to the OP question ? for example, one could specialize/overload std::get to work with an empty tuple, and given that the get template argument depends on foo template parameter, I don't think we can prove that *every* valid specialization requires an empty pack ...

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes A sufficiently clever compiler is free to use the knowledge that 1) no such `std::get` overloads/specializations are provided by the standard library and 2) no user code can add such overloads/specializations, on pain of UB.

Comment: @T.C. I think the OP is interested in the general question concerning templates, rather than those using std:: members. Clearly, your comment does not apply to the general case ...

Comment: @T.C. secondly, I believe such a broad reading of the standardese goes against its orginal intent ( that is, early cathing of template errors ), see my answer ...

Comment: @T.C. at best, your answer should be completed with a quote concerning non overlodability/specializability of std members; note that it would suffice adding a std::get using directive and making an unqualified call to neutralize your argument ...

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes There's no non-`std` namespaces for ADL to look at for `std::tuple<>` in the instantiation context.