# template, well formedness and zero pack length rule

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, variadic-templates, well-formed

From the accepted answer of [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46474889/zero-length-variadic-expansion-of-ill-formed-call) I've discovered [a rule](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.res#8) I didn't know about templates and well formedness

> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> - [...]
> - every valid specialization of a variadic template requires an empty template parameter pack, or
> - [...]

According this rule (if I understand correctly), the following template function is ill-formed

```
template <typename ... Ts>
int foo (std::tuple<Ts...> const &)
 { return std::get<sizeof...(Ts)>(std::tuple<int>{42}); }
```

because the only valid specialization require and empty `Ts...` parameter pack.

But (maybe because I don't know English very well) I'm not sure to understand this rule in case of a template with two ore more parameter packs.

I mean... the following `foo()` function

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template <typename ... Ts, typename ... Us>
int foo (std::tuple<Ts...> const &, std::tuple<Us...> const &)
 { return std::get<sizeof...(Ts)+sizeof...(Us)-1U>(std::tuple<int>{42}); }

int main ()
 {
   auto t0 = std::tuple<>{};
   auto t1 = std::tuple<int>{0};

   //std::cout << foo(t0, t0) << std::endl; // compilation error
   std::cout << foo(t0, t1) << std::endl;   // print 42
   std::cout << foo(t1, t0) << std::endl;   // print 42
   //std::cout << foo(t1, t1) << std::endl; // compilation error
 }
```

is well-formed or ill-formed?

Because a valid specialization of it require that `Ts...` **or** `Us...` is empty (and that the other parameter pack is exactly of size 1).

The rule should be interpreted in the sense that a programm is ill-formed if there is an empty parameter pack that must be ever empty (so my example should be well formed because both parameter packs can be not empty) or in the sense that is ill-formed if in every specialization there is at least an empty parameter pack, not necessarily the same in every specialization (so my example should be ill-formed) ?

Comment: I think you are mistaking specialization for instantiation. I mean that given example contains just a template function with no specializations.

Comment: To be honest I don't quite get this condition either. However if "specialization" is used there as "instantiation" that would make no sense at all, for example instantiating `template<int V, typename...> class foo{};` like `foo<0>` and `foo<1>` would make program ill-formed since both the "specializations" would require an empty template parameters pack.

Comment: @VTT - sorry for my preceding comment: I've misunderstood the point 4

Comment: @VTT - maybe you're right; maybe I've misunderstood the full rule.

Comment: @VTT - still trying to understand... from a book ("C++ common knowledge", SC Dewhurst) I read "A Specialization of a template is what you when you supply a template with a set of template argument"; regarding the specialization of a template function "when we write print(12.3), we are impliciting specializing the print function template with a function template". According this definition, the four calls to `foo()` (two commented) in my example causing four (two) specializations of `foo()`. Do you agree? (sorry but I have to go and I'm away for some hours)

Comment: I believe the name of _"what happens with templates when calling `foo()`"_ is called (implicit) instantiation. Specialization refers to providing an alternative definition to the primary template.

Comment: Upon further reading, a specialization is the resulting class/function from (implicitly or explicitly) applying a particular set of arguments to a template. In the words of the standard *"Unless a class template specialization has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the class template specialization is implicitly instantiated[...]"*

Comment: @PasserBy - I'm a little confused because I'm used to think to a "specialization" as an alternative class definition (partial or full) or function definition (only full). But I've found a definition equivalent (I think) to the one you've transcribed and, it seems to me, in the document where the rule is present, the meaning of "specialization" is the second one.

Answer (score 1):

I think the intent of the rule has not been communicated clearly by the standard wording and perhaps never will.

The "no valid specialization" rule is intended to allow compilers to perform early diagnosis of constructs that are grammatically valid but can be seen to be semantically nonsensical without having to instantiate the template. Here's an example:

```
template <int x>
void foo() {
    typedef double D;
    x.~D();
}
```

There's nothing grammatically wrong with this. Semantically, this is trying to destroy a value of type `int` as if it were of type `double`, which is of course not allowed. If you instantiate `foo` then the compiler is allowed to diagnose it, but isn't required to. It seems that Clang gives a diagnostic, while GCC doesn't.

In the same vein, the intent of the rule about template parameter packs is that if the pattern for a pack expansion is semantically nonsensical, then the compiler is allowed to diagnose it early. A variant of the above example illustrates this:

```
template <int... x>
void foo() {
    typedef double D;
    (x.~D(), ...);
}
```

The only way this can be well-formed is if there are 0 instances of `x.~D()` in the expansion; even 1 will always be ill-formed. So the idea here is that the compiler is allowed (but not required) to diagnose the ill-formed pattern even though it's possible to get a well-formed specialization by supplying an empty pack that results in 0 elements in the expansion.

(Again, GCC is ok with this, and even lets you call `foo<>()`. Clang diagnoses it even when it's not instantiated.)

Based on that, the rule when there are two parameter packs *should* be:

- If the only thing you do with them is use `sizeof...`, then the rule about every valid specialization requiring an empty pack shouldn't even apply at all. It's not in the "spirit" of the current rule.
- If you expand them *individually*, then the rule should be that *if there exists at least one pack such that pack must be empty in order to get a valid instantiation* then the program is IFNDR. That means the compiler is allowed to diagnose either ill-formed pattern.
- If you do a *nested* expansion, i.e., you have a pattern that contains one of the packs, you expand it, and then that's part of a larger expression that also contains the second pack, and *that* is also expanded (so the result has MN elements, where M is the number of elements in the first pack and N is the number of elements in the second pack) then the rule should be that *if every valid instantiation requires at least one pack to be empty* then the program is IFNDR.